# jquery dialog post values to php page

Tags: php, jquery, forms, modal-dialog

i am completely new to JQuery.

I would like to get a solution on how to pass values from a jquery dialog form to a php file for proccessing.

Please refer to [this link](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) as an example of the [jquery dialog form](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form)

Please note: The example of the dialog form passes values to a table and displays. In my case I would like to pass them to another page(.php file).

Your assistance is much appreciated :)

Code:
-Script

```
if(bValid)
{
  $.post("scripts/appointment.php",{  name: name.val(),
                                     email: email.val(),
                                   contact: contact.val(),
                                      file: filenumber.val(), 
                                    reason: reason.val(),
                                  app_date: appdate.val(),
                                      time: apptime().val,
                                     visit: getRadioValue()},
                     function(data){
                         $("#dialog-form").slideUp("normal", function() {
                         $("#dialog-form").before('<h1>Success</h1><p>Your Appointment was sent.</p>');
 }); }
);  

   $( this ).dialog( "close" );
 }
```

-form

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Make an appointment">
  <p class="validateTips">Please fill in the form to book an appointment.<br>If the
  booking is not available we will notify you!</p>

   <form>
     <fieldset>
       <label for="patient"><b>First Time Visit?</b></label>
     <input type="radio" name="patient" id="patient_state" value="Yes">Yes<br>
 <input type="radio" name="patient" id="patient_state" value="No">No<br><hr>
<label for="filenumber">File No.</label>
<input type="text" name="filenumber" id="filenumber" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
<label for="reason">What's your reason for visit?</label>
<input type="text" name="reason" id="reason" value="type reason here..." class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
<label for="contact">Contact No.</label>
<input type="text" name="contact" id="contact" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
<label for="appdate">Date</label>
<input type="text" name="appdate" id="datepicker" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
<label for="apptime">Time</label>
 <input type="text" name="apptime" id="apptime" value="HH:MM" class="text ui-widget-  
 content ui-corner-all" />
  </fieldset>
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi DevZer0,the link on my question will take you to the code. But i understand why you asking that now... let me post the full code. Thanks.

Comment: @21stking It will take you to jQuery UI's code, not yours

Comment: @vladkras I have posted my code now, you can check it.

Comment: @21stking ok, and what's wrong with this code? You've got an error?

Comment: @vladkras , i do not get an error. when i click "Book" button nothing happens, the form even stays open it doesnt close. I want the values to be passes to the scripts/aappointment.php file when i click the "Book" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this means you have to bind click event on your book button:

```
$('#bookButton').click(function() {
    // perfom check
    if (bValid) {
        // other code
    }
});
```

Comment: i do have an event handler for my button and it works, the problem lies in posting my values to another page. i.e inside the if(bvalid){ // other code }

Comment: i have figured out what is the problem. the problem is with the values that i am trying to pass( name.val(), email.val(), etc).. when i hard code the values it works fine but when i reference them they dont work